# Google sheets:find matching items in a table from two criteria, and multiply cells from found rows as a result

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a big sheet with a lot of data (bill of material type) and I want to count the total number of parts. It unfortunately involves multiplying cells. Here is a sample sheet i created:

[Counting fruits](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18irJprxBtPkAp3J2Y4_m3E8CDyAKf6c-2o1kPPKPPKY/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to basically count the number of apples from France that are listed in the sheet. For each row, there is a quantity of fruits per crate and the number of crates for that fruit. I am determined to get the total number of fruits by multiplying the values in D*E.

[sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5fRd.png)

I have tried to use a query, but it returns an error:

```
=QUERY(A2:E20,"select A,B, sum(D*E) group by A,B")
```

I previously looked into CountIf, but it didn't feel appropriate.

My real application is a bit more complex, but this is a good start. I would prefer to avoid adding columns to help with the calcs.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't edit, but the title should say 'find matching items in a table from two criteria, and multiply cells from found rows as a result'

Comment: pnuts, it seems to have worked this time!

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=Arrayformula(query({A2:F20, D2:D20*E2:E20}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col7) WHERE Col1 <>'' GROUP BY Col1, Col2 LABEL SUM(Col7) 'TOTAL', Col1 'Fruit', Col2 'Origin' ", 0))
```

Change range to suit.

Comment: Hi JPV,I manage to get all the data in a new table which is cool, but I wish to have is to display the results for whichever item {fruit+origin} on its corresponding row.
Understandably, the sum results may be common on more than one row!